# How to highlight selected row in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS I want the selected row in the table to be highlighted when the user goes from 'home page' to 'details page'.

I tried below code for do my requirement but it's not working.

### home.html

```
<div ng-repeat="employee in employeeList">
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-class="{'panel-success' : employee.id===selectedId}">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">{{employee.name}}</h3>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### HomePage

```
routerApp.controller('EmployeeController', function ($scope, $state,dataService) {
   $scope.selectedId = dataService.getId();
    $scope.viewEmployee = function (employeeId) {
        $state.go('employeeDetails', { employeeId: employeeId });
    }
})
```

### DetailsPage

```
routerApp.controller('EmployeeDetailsController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state,dataService) {
    $scope.goBack = function () {
      dataService.setId($stateParams.employeeId);
        $state.go('employeeList');
    }
})
```

### Service

```
routerApp.service("dataService", function () {
    var employeeId;
    this.setId = function (id) {
        employeeId = id;
    }
    this.getId = function () {
        return employeeId;
    }
});
```

Comment: No one have idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use brackets inside the `ng-class`. Refactor like this.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-class="{'panel-success':employee.id===selectedId}">
```

Comment: how can i get back selectedId when user goes home to details page?

Comment: since ngclass is angular directive, u don't need to use the `{{}}` to render the scope variable. Angular do that for u. Also no need to use the ternary condition in here because if the `employee.id===selectedId` condition failed the `success` class will get removed.

Comment: As per `selectedId` variable. if u use the same variable across different controls i suggest use a service or factory

Comment: can you please do that ?it will more helpfull me

Comment: updare the code where u use the `selectedId` in controller

Comment: i am using $rootScope in detail controller for getback selectedId in employeeList

Comment: Is this good idea if not please guide me better way to do this

Comment: check this https://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185702/discussion-between-abhiram-and-sachila-ranawaka).